# Assumption of element for integration

Tags: electricity, electric-current

In a round wire of cross sectional radius $R$, current density varies with the radial distance from axis of wire as  $J=Cx^2 \, \mathrm{A/m^2}$. Find total current flowing in wire. ($J$ = Current density)

## My Attempt

If we assume a ring at a distance $x$ and thickness $\mathrm dx$ then $\mathrm dI = Cx^22 \pi x \, \mathrm dx$ and on integrating we get answer as $\frac 12 \pi C R^4$. That's okay but what if we assume a disc of radius $x$ instead of a ring. How to solve then? 
From where will the $\mathrm dx$ term come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the current density varies with radius, you cannot choose a disc of radius $x$ as a surface element. What the integral do is to sum the current over all elements. This is only possible if the current over each element is well defined. When choosing an element of integration (area in your  case) you have to choose one whose the physical quantity you are integrating (in your case the density current) is constant over that element. Notice that the product of $J$ with the area of a finite disc does not make sense since there would be an ambiguity on which $x$ in $J(x)$ you should use.